# How to have inputs work while having a listener on keyDown, keyUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large canvas in which I spawn a normally fixed HTML element in a fixed location.

This HTML element has a `input`, no matter what I try and do the input will literally not accept any input. I click on the element, the cursor is blinking, and when I attempt to type my keystroke almost seems like they are not being registered and nothing happens.

I had the input wrapped in a `form`, later wrapped it in a div, and still nothing.

```
return ( <div> <input/> </div> );
```

The input is not disabled or anything, what would stop me from being able to type in it?
Are there global events I'm not aware of that could just stop inputs from working?

EDIT:

After a comment gave me an idea...

I have a `useEffect` that capture a `keydown` affect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', onDragEventDown);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', onDragEventUp);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', onDragEventDown);
        window.addEventListener('keyup', onDragEventUp);
    };
}, [onDragEventUp, onDragEventDown]);
```

In the parent of this, I removed these listeners, and the input worked again.

So it seems that this was causing issues because each keyDown/keyUp causes a re-render, which makes sense. How can I have these active while listening for special keys?

Comment: what the issue with `readonly` attribute?

Comment: Sounds like you rerender input on every focus, please create an example like expected: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why you are not applying onChange, onKeyDown. onKeyUp on input field?

Comment: When using React, you generally don’t need to call addEventListener to add listeners to a DOM element after it is created. Instead, just provide a listener when the element is initially rendered.

Comment: Do you want onDragEventDown, onDragEventUp also to get executed while you are typing?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events.

Still if you want to go with above approach use document object not window,

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownEventHandeler);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDownEventHandeler);
    };
}, [onKeyUpEventHandeler, onKeyDownEventHandeler]);

onKeyDownEventHandeler= (event) => {
      if(event.key === keyName){
        // Code here
      }
}
```